# Classification of $G$-principal Bundle and classification of $G$-coverings: a bridge between the two?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I encountered the following sentence in an exercise (the context is irrelevant)

> Let $G\cong\langle s_1,s_2,\dots , s_g \mid R \rangle$ be a discrete one relator group. Consider the $G$-principal covering associated to the projection $p\colon \ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z} \to G $, $q\colon Y \to B( \ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z})$

I think there are two reasonable interpretations of this sentence:

> 1) let $K:=\ker(p)$, we have an associated (up to iso) covering to $K$. We know that the Deck transformation group is isomorphic to $N(K)/K\cong G$ and hence it's a $G$-covering.

and

> 2) let $\tilde{p} \colon B(\ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z})\to BG$ be the map associated to $p \in \hom_{Grp}(\ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z}, G)$ (both spaces are E-M spaces) and do the pullback of $\xi \colon EG\to BG$ via $\tilde{p}$ so we obtain a $G$-principal bundle, but being $G$ discrete, it's a $G$-principal cover.

I was curios about these two ways to interpret the sentence and so I asked myself wether was possible to draw some lines between the two:

I explain clearly what I mean by that. Under the assumption of $G$ being a discrete group, the $G$ bundle builded in $2)$ is a covering of $B(\ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z})$, ad hence it's classified by a subgroup of $\ast_{i=1}^g\mathbb{Z}$ (up to conjugation). With the l.e.s for a Serre Fibration one can prove (according to me) that the cardinality of such subgroup has to be the same of the cardinality of $\ker(p)$, but I really don't know wether it is possible to show that this covering is isomorphic to the one classified by $\ker(p)$ in general.

My question therefore is if one can say something more between these two constructions or if the exercise should have been more specific

Comment: If $G$ is discrete, then principal $G$-bundles are the same thing as $G$-covers.

Comment: yes, I think I wrote that. I was curious, or maybe confused, about how to pass from the usual classification of $G$ bundles given by maps into $BG$ and the classification of $G$-covers of $BG$ given by subgroups of $G$. It's possible that the question is not clearly written, tomorrow morning I'll clean it up if this is necessary

Comment: It's covers of $BG$ that are classified by (conjugacy classes of) subgroups of $G$. $G$-covers of $BG$ are classified by maps $BG \to BG$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought about your comments and I can't see what is your point. It's entirely possible that I'm overlooking something trivial and if that's the case I apologise. I rewrote the last part of the question hoping that now is more clear what is my doubt

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was using terminology a little carelessly. There are two things you might mean by "$G$-cover" and they're not the same:

- A Galois cover with automorphism group $G$.
- A principal $G$-bundle.

For example, consider the trivial principal $G$-bundle $X \times G$ on any reasonable space $X$. This is not a Galois cover because $X \times G$ is not connected, even if $X$ is, and it does not have automorphism group $G$: its automorphism group, as a cover, is one copy of the symmetric group $S_{|G|}$ for every connected component of $X$.

In any case, I think the second interpretation was the intended one.